# Change Username?

Tags: multisite, username, network-admin

A while back I was able to change the user-name in the `wp_users` table without problem. I noticed today that is not the case, or at least not with the super-admin user role.

How can I adjust the user-name for a super-admin? I'm simply changing a user name first character from uppercase to lowercase. It's not a big deal, except it is driving the perfectionist in me crazy. It would also be useful to know.

I also attempted to serialize the database without luck.

Comment: Not an answer but plugins as a utility is nice. I use [Username Changer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/username-changer/) for simplicity.

Comment: Is it in multisite installation ?

Comment: It is a multisite installation. I installed that plugin, @Howdy_McGee. The username plugin did not work on the current WP v. and with super admin, both root site and network enabled.

Comment: I'm able to change the `user_login` value in `wp_users` for a super admin user without issue. Tested on a local installation, change made using SequelPro. Perhaps something else is affecting the name change?

Comment: I'm using PHP MyAdmin and attempted to change that value without success. This is the initial user account. I wonder if that has anything to do with it..